# intercept JSON in C# to return a list of nullable boolean

Tags: c#, json, json.net, interceptor

I am getting an error when I try to return a list of nullable boolean from my JSON interceptor.
The interceptor attribute is:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(NullableBoolListDeSerializer))]
public List<bool?> ExemptBenefits { get; set; }
```

The ReadJSON method on the interceptor is:

```
 List<bool?> result = new List<bool?>();

        (reader as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenReader).CurrentToken.ToList().ForEach(item =>
        {
            string value = (String)item.ToObject(typeof(String));
            switch (value.ToLower())
            {
                case "true":
                case "yes":
                case "1":
                    result.Add(true);
                    break;
                case "false":
                case "no":
                case "0":
                default:
                    result.Add(false);
                    break;
            }
        });
        return result;
```

The JSON being submitted is:

```
{
  "exemptBenefits": [
     "1"
  ],
  "_apiEndpoint": "/benefits/loan"
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Unexpected token when deserializing object: String. Path 'exemptBenefits[0]', line 1, position 187.
```

Wondering how to convert a list of strings (eg "1","0"."true", "false") from JSON to a List (true,false,true,false) in a JSON interceptor 
(actually it is NewtonSoft.Json)

Comment: Showing the input JSON would help.

Comment: I have added the JSON that is being submitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert a list of string values into a list of nullable boolean values with a `JsonConverter` class, I would recommend using a `JArray` inside the converter instead of trying to deal with the reader directly.  This will allow you to simplify your code while also avoiding the error you encountered:

```
class NullableBoolListDeSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    readonly string[] TrueStrings = { "true", "yes", "1" };

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<bool?>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return JArray.Load(reader)
            .Children<JValue>()
            .Select(jv =>
            {
                string b = (string)jv;
                return b != null ? TrueStrings.Contains(b.ToLower()) : (bool?)null;
            })
            .ToList();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JaP5W7

Of course, you can actually do better than that.  Instead of making your converter handle a `List<bool?>`, make it handle just a simple `bool?` instead, e.g.:

```
class NullableBoolDeSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    readonly string[] TrueStrings = { "true", "yes", "1" };

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(bool?);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string b = (string)reader.Value;
        return b != null ? TrueStrings.Contains(b.ToLower()) : (bool?)null;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then, swap out the `[JsonConverter]` attribute on your `ExemptBenefits` property declaration for a `[JsonProperty]` attribute that has its `ItemConverterType` parameter set to the simplified converter.  Json.Net will then handle creating the list for you.

```
[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(NullableBoolDeSerializer))]
public List<bool?> ExemptBenefits { get; set; }
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dp4N11

Comment: No problem; glad to help.